# swt.widgets.List returns empty

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have developed an eclipse plugin with few wizard pages. In one of the pages, am using `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List`

My code goes as follows:

```
public void createControl(Composite parent){
    // few lines of code
    List classesList = new List(someComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    if(hugeList!=null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < hugeList.size(); j++){
            String a= hugeList.get(j);
            classesList.add(a);
            System.out.println("Inside loop: " + classesList);
        }
        System.out.println("Outside loop: " + classesList);
    }
    classesList.addListener(SWT.Selection, this);
    // lines of code
}
```

Here, based upon the size of `hugeList` the `Inside loop:` keeps printing the data.
But, for `Outside loop:` the list is **empty** :(

I couldn't understand the reason. Can someone please help.

Comment: I'm assuming the two opening brackets here: "`System.out.println(("Outside loop: " + classesList);`" are just a typo?

Comment: Corrected. its a typo.

Comment: I would suggest using List#getItemCount() in the sysout lines. The toString() method of a widget is not that representative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer here lies in the way that you've attempted to print the information. `System.out.println("Outside loop: " + classesList)` will implicitly call `classesList.toString()`. SWT widgets' toString() methods (unless otherwise overridden) form the general pattern:

```
ClassName {otherInformation}
```

However, it is up to subclasses to fill `otherInformation` with useful data by overriding `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getNameText()`. `List` doesn't do this, so `otherInformation` is simply the empty string, and toString() will always<sup>[1]</sup> return `List {}`.

To get the information from that `List` that you require, call `getItems()`.

<sub>[1] unless it is disposed or is called on the wrong thread.</sub>